# File mapping IPC hangs on MapViewOfFile call

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, ipc

I have a legacy code that uses File Mapping ([slides 8-9](http://www.slideshare.net/mfsi_vinothr/ipc-mechanisms-in-windows)) to do IPC. But when there is a high load of reads and writes through the channel, the writer thread hangs on `MapViewOfFile`. MSDN has no information on blocking behaviour of `MapViewOfFile`. What're the possible reasons?

While the whole source could be [found on github](https://github.com/pingidentity/browser-extensions/blob/win8-mem-leaks/ie/source/proxy/Channel.cpp), the relevant part of the code is

```
BOOL Channel::Read(LPVOID data, DWORD dataSize, BOOL response/* = FALSE*/)
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject(m_events[response 
                                   ? RESPONSE_AVAILABLE 
                                   : REQUEST_AVAILABLE], 
                          INFINITE);

    LPVOID source = ::MapViewOfFile(m_section, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, dataSize);
    if (!source) {
        if (!response) {
            ::SetEvent(m_events[SERVER_AVAILABLE]);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::CopyMemory(data, source, dataSize);
    BOOL ok = ::UnmapViewOfFile(source);

    if (!response) {
        ::SetEvent(m_events[SERVER_AVAILABLE]);
    }

    return ok;
}

BOOL Channel::Write(LPVOID data, DWORD dataSize, BOOL response/* = FALSE*/)
{
    if (!response) {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(m_events[SERVER_AVAILABLE], INFINITE);
    }

    LPVOID destination = ::MapViewOfFile(m_section, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, dataSize);
    if (!destination) {
        if(!response) {
            ::SetEvent(m_events[SERVER_AVAILABLE]);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::CopyMemory(destination, data, dataSize);
    if (::UnmapViewOfFile(destination)) {
        ::SetEvent(m_events[response 
                           ? RESPONSE_AVAILABLE 
                           : REQUEST_AVAILABLE]);
        return TRUE;

    } else {
        ::SetEvent(m_events[(response 
                             ? RESPONSE_AVAILABLE 
                             : SERVER_AVAILABLE)]);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the call to `MapViewOfFile` hangs indefinitely, you can create a dump file (e.g. using Task Manager) for later analysis. WinDbg's [!locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563980.aspx) command can then be used to identify the synchronization object that's being waited on.

Comment: It is fugly, throw this away and use a named pipe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Probably, the best recommendation I've ever heard. I would be eager to throw away the whole source of OpenForge (Aviro antivirus even detects its descendants as hazardous applications).

Comment: One possible reason is the swap - MapViewOfFile will swap out memory if there is not enough. Are you sure you have enough physical memory during this time?

Comment: @SergeyA Looks like this is it. The issue comes most likely on the QA's VM rather than on a developer machine. I'll check it further tomorrow. Would you be so kind to post this as an answer? :)

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject()` can return unexpectedly, you should check for errors there. Further, why do you repeatedly map and unmap the file? Do that once, just like you only set up the events for synchronization once.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the OP, posting my comment as an answer.

One possible reason for this behaviour would be shortage of physical memory. MapViewOfFile has to swap out some memory in this case, and this process is time-consuming. It is easy to verify this assumption by checking memory stats when the problem manifests itself.